# Same JSch Channel object is used for long term, could cause memory issue

Tags: ssh, jsch

We are reading the files using JSch Channel continuously from a specific location. There is another program that adds the files on designated location continuously and from same location the JSch read the files.

We observed that the memory is getting increased, if we run the application for long time. Here, we are not closing the JSch channel/session connection and same connection we are using. So question is, does the use of same JSch channel/session object could cause the high memory usage?
is it recommended to use the same connection for long time, or shall we open and close the connection after specific interval or on every request/response?

Expert could you please help me on this.

Thanks,